# Graphing functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am having problems understanding how to graph the product $fg$ when $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = |x|$.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $(fg)(x)=x^2$ for $x\ge0$, and $(fg)(x)=-x^2$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to rewrite $g(x) = |x|$ as a piecewise function:

$$g(x) = \left \{ 
\begin{array}{lr} 
-x & x < 0 \\
x & x \geq 0 \\ 
\end{array} \right.$$

Then the product is also a piecewise function.

$$(fg)(x) = \left \{ 
\begin{array}{lr} 
-x^2 & x < 0 \\
x^2 & x \geq 0 \\ 
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: I dont know how i missed using both the negative values! thank you! i see my mistake